# Pretty URLs for bilingual site

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using quite a simple and straightforward session switch to make my site bilingual.
I'd like to make the URLs a bit more SEO friendly and pretty like this - *site.com/en/services* so that is displayed only the value of the query *da* or *en*. Ideally before the page name in the URL. So far the site is quite simple and there are no subdirectories, which I learned might make a difference.

So far I'm not using any router, only .htaccess configurations

Language switch program:

```
 <?php session_start();

// Define a list of supported languages to avoid arbitrary file inclusion
$supportedLanguages = ['en', 'da'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
} else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], $supportedLanguages)) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
// Ensure the requested language file exists before requiring it
$languageFile = "languages/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
if (file_exists($languageFile)) {
    require_once $languageFile;
} else {
    // Handle the case where the language file doesn't exist (e.g., fallback to a default language).
    // You can add code here to provide a graceful error message or take other appropriate actions.
    die("Language file not found.");
}
?>
```

HTML Swich interface:

```
  <li role="menuitem">
            <?php if($_SESSION['lang']=="da"){
              echo '<a class="language-switch" href="?lang=en">EN</a>';
            }
            else if($_SESSION['lang']=="en"){
              echo '<a class="language-switch" href="?lang=da">DA</a>';
            } ?>
          </li>
```

.htaccess:

```
# Page not found / 404 set-up
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine on

# does not apply to existing directories, meaning that if the folder exists on the server then don't change anything and don't run the Rule!
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Check for file in directory with .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

# Here we actually show the page that has the .php extension
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
# RewriteRule (.*) routes.php [QSA,L]

DirectoryIndex /index.php
```

Comment: You haven’t stated any actual problems, just your setup. Is this not working?

Comment: If you aren’t using a router, you probably have a bunch of repeated code that includes shared things like headers and footers. Adding a router greatly simplifies this.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I’d like to have this solution but I’m not really sure how. For components I use somethings else

Comment: _"So far I'm not using any router"_ - Routers are for make your URL's exactly like you want them in an easier and more portable and compatible way. It's definitely the best tool for the job. If use htaccess (which is for Apache) and want/need to move the app to a different web server in the future, like nginx, you would need to write the same rules again using that servers rewrite format. Even if you don't think you will move it now, things can change.

Comment: Okay, how the router should look like to perform the issue I stated above, please?

Answer (score 0):

As previously suggested by everyone, utilizing a route for this purpose will help prevent a lot of headaches in the future. Here's a very basic implementation you can take a look.

**index.php:**

```php
<?php session_start();

function route($url)
{
    switch ($url) {
        case '/':
            require_once 'languages/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php';
            include 'views/home.php';
            break;
        default:
            include '404.php';
            break;
    }
}

$supportedLanguages = ['en', 'da'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
} else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], $supportedLanguages)) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}

$route = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
route($route);
```

**home.php (Example content):**

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $_SESSION['lang']; ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Language Switch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $language['welcome']; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $language['intro']; ?></p>

    <ul role="menu">
        <li role="menuitem">
            <?php if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "da") {
                echo '<a class="language-switch" href="?lang=en">EN</a>';
            } else if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "en") {
                echo '<a class="language-switch" href="?lang=da">DA</a>';
            } ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**en.php:**

```php
<?php

$language = [
    'welcome' => 'Welcome!',
    'intro' => 'This is the English version of the page.'
];
```

**da.php:**

```php
<?php

$language = [
    'welcome' => 'Velkommen!',
    'intro' => 'Dette er den danske version af siden.'
];
```

**.htaccess:**

```bash
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex /index.php
```

Comment: I think this misses the specific requirement that OP is looking for, to include the lang code as the first segment of the uri - _"site.com/en/services"_. Also, `.htaccess` should probably be rewriting all requests to `index.php`, when requested file/directory does not exist.